# How can I temporally stop sending info to a consumer in RabbitMQ?

Tags: api, rabbitmq, celery

I have a python fastapi using Celery to send/receive messages to RabbitMQ so I can have tasks in a queue. The api runs in a docker, and RabbitMQ runs in a different docker.

My API works grate, and the connection is well established. However, now I need to update the API docker and here I have a problem: While doing the update I want my API docker not to process any Celery task. What I thought is to temporally block the access to the API from the server, block RabbitMQ to send to Celery back tasks to do, update the API docker, wait until a new connection with RabbitMQ is done and everything is up and undo the block access to the API from the server.

Is this the correct way to proceed? How can I make RabbitMQ to stop sending back tasks to Celery while updating the API docker?

Comment: Why? One of the points of offloading tasks to Celery is that if your worker goes down (e.g. for an update), messages will be queued up in RabbitMQ, and then when the worker comes back online, it will process all the queued messages.

Comment: In the API docker there is a solo worker making tasks that can span up to 1 minute. I wasn't sure if I kill the docker directly, the task will be send back to Rabbit. Will it be? or will I lose it?